# OpenAPI / Swagger Spec: how to specify an entire example request body?

Tags: rest, swagger-2.0, openapi

I have some APIs that consume `application/json` and I would like to add an example request body using Open API 2.0 / Swagger Spec 2.0. This is similar to how you can add an entire example response body in the `responses.200.examples.application/json` property here:

- https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/examples/v2.0/yaml/api-with-examples.yaml

I've been looking through the spec and can only find specific examples of property values, not the entire request body.

This is a standard feature of the OpenAPI 3.0 spec but my toolchain hasn't migrated to it yet. Here's an example in the 3.0 spec:

- https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.0.md#example-object-example

I'm currently thinking of three custom property approaches for a 2.0 spec:

- a custom `x-requests.examples.application/json` property in the path endpoint object. This would match the `responses.200.examples.application/json` property.
- a custom `x-examples.application/json` property in the `in=body` JSON body parameter. This would be more closely tied to the request schema object reference.
- a custom `x-requestBody.content.application/json.examples.default.value` in the path endpoint object. This would match the OpenAPI 3.0 implementation which has a native `requestBody` property.

Is there a standard way to do this using OpenAPI 2.0 / Swagger 2.0 spec?